# Change parameters for default gnome-screenshot call (shortcut)?

Tags: gnome, gnome-screenshot

I would like to "fix" the call to `gnome-screenshot` that is used when I press the PrintSc key. Is this command hard-coded in some gnome binary? I am searching in the whole system, and I cannot find where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Activities" and type in `key`

Select "Keyboard shortcuts"

[image]

Click on the entry you'd like to change and provide it with a new keyboard shortcut....

If you want another action to be taken when pressing the "PrintSc" button got to the bottom of that List and press the "+" button:

[image]

Comment: Create a new shortcut is a sort of workaround. I was looking for a way to edit the command in order to restore the previous behavior where just press PrintSc means copy instead save.

Comment: Ah - you want another action to be taken when pressing PressSc? Then scroll down and press the + sign